# Why is UITextField text setter giving [UIView text] selector not recognized

Tags: ios, uitextfield, unrecognized-selector

I have this code:

```
- (IBAction)setButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults.santiapps.com"];
    NSLog(@"nsuserdef %@", [sharedDefaults objectForKey:@"MyNumberKey"]);
    NSLog(@"self.textField.text %@", self.textField.text);

    //[sharedDefaults setInteger:[self.textField.text integerValue] forKey:@"MyNumberKey"];

    [sharedDefaults synchronize];   // (!!) This is crucial.
    NSLog(@"syncd");

}
```

and for some reason when I tap the button, I get:

```
-[UIView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

but my property is set as:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

I get a crash if I uncommment the sharedDefaults setInteger line.

I get a crash if I leave the line where I read the self.textField.text.

I get the final syncd NSLog only if I comment-out the setInteger or self.textField.text NSLog lines.

Why is it thinking textField is a UIView without a text property?

Comment: You must have associated the wrong view with your outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, don't mean to toot my own horn here, but I thought the answer might help someone.

Xcode had incorrectly linked my view controller's UIView to the outlet.  And I know some will think I would have done it by being careless, except that I did it as I very seldomly do the connection:

I control dragged from the textfield to the assistant editor's interface where xcode itself created the IBOutlet UITextField for me.  So I know it wasn't my mistake. :)

Xcode is buggy. So watch out :-)